# How can I use httpOnly cookies with Vue3 app and Node server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authentication, cookies, single-page-application

I have a node server that is running in **port 3000** and a Vue 3 app that is running in **port 8080**.

I am using the httpOnly cookie for a **refresh token** and another token as an **access token**.

I can send an access token in the "**Authorization**" header. But as the refresh token is httpOnly cookie I can not send it manually with Axios.

My API URL is '**http://localhost:3000/api**'

When I send a request from my Vue app(http://localhost:3000) browser does not send the httpOnly cookie automatically.

Server headers:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
);
res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Content-Type, Origin, Authorization'
);
```

What can I do?

If the browser does not send the httpOnly cookie automatically, I can not use it in my node server for authentication.